# Google Map API is not trying to load tiles(pictures)/showing blank map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Background: I've had a embedded google map working fine for a while(around 2 years).It stops working recently (these couple days, cannot tell exact time). I do have a API key which is working.

By not working I mean: 
API is loaded. 
Map is initialized, you can even draw markers on it. 
However, the background(the pictures of map,tiles?) is not loaded. And seems it is not even make request to get the tiles. The whole "map area" is blank, you can move around(I see from console it tries to get new viewpoint when I do "move").
And no error was logged.

I tried their simple map example with my API key, which works.
Tried the essentially same code with our website server, it stops working.

In the developer's dashboard (where you can see the # of request made with your API key). I found all the failed ones does not register here.
So I figure there's something with the authentication? But I can figure out why it is working in one case but not the other.

Since it has been working for 2 years, code probably does not matter. But the testing page code here just in case, quite literally copy from their example:

```
<script>
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
        });
    }

</script>
<style>
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[my api key here]&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
```

Any help/idea are appropriated, thanks ahead!

Comment: The posted code works for me.  Is your HTML really missing the `<head>` and `<html>` tags?  In either case it works as a local file (without a key).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Do you have a firewall?  Have you tried it from a different computer/browser/location?

Comment: If you open the browser console and check network activity, can you see requests of type `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=...` ? What is the status code of responses for these requests?

Comment: 1) Check the above suggestions 2) If the tiles are loading, don't you have any additional CSS that would somehow hide the map images? 3) By not specifying an API version in your API call, you get the experimental version of the API. Did you try your code with the release version?

Comment: @xomena that's what I was trying to say, those request were not made(they were there).

Comment: @geocodezip no firewall as far as I know, and the those set-up has been working for two years+. No environment changes as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I must didn't read the doc carefully that I don't even know you can choose to load a specific version. That probably would have solve the issue and save a lot of time. Thx for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally found the solution(at least for my environment).
After replacing collectionjs(made from browserify) with a newer version, it all works out. Looks like something with the global namespace(or whatever you would call it).

Don't know if this is a known/common issue(please let me know if it is). Just put out my solution in case someone ran into exact situation.

Once again, thx for everyone that trying to help!